I need the regular expression to extract the legcount details from the response in JMeter
I need the value of outbound and inbound flight details from <a:LegCount>1 </a:LegCount> and <a:LegCount>2</a:LegCount> tags respectively. There are multiple tags in the response.
I am using the below regular expression, but it is not working. It picks only the first value instead of the <a:LegCount>1 </a:LegCount> value.
Outbound:
<a:FlightSegment>[.\s\S]+?<a:LFID>(.+?)<.a:LFID>[.\s\S]+?<a:DepartureDate>(.+?)T(.+?)<.a:DepartureDate>[.\s\S]+?<a:LegCount>1<.a:LegCount>[.\s\S]+?<a:FCCode>(.+?)<.a:FCCode>[.\s\S]+?<a:FBCode>(.+?)<.a:FBCode>[.\s\S]+?<a:SegmentDetail>[.\s\S]+?<a:Origin>(.+?)</a:Origin>[.\s\S]+?<a:Destination>(.+?)</a:Destination>
Inbound:
<a:FlightSegment>[.\s\S]+?<a:LFID>(.+?)<.a:LFID>[.\s\S]+?<a:DepartureDate>(.+?)T(.+?)<.a:DepartureDate>[.\s\S]+?<a:LegCount>2<.a:LegCount>[.\s\S]+?<a:FCCode>(.+?)<.a:FCCode>[.\s\S]+?<a:FBCode>(.+?)<.a:FBCode>[.\s\S]+?<a:SegmentDetail>[.\s\S]+?<a:Origin>(.+?)</a:Origin>[.\s\S]+?<a:Destination>(.+?)</a:Destination>
Response:
<a:FlightSegment>
                        <a:LFID>132861</a:LFID>
                        <a:DepartureDate>2024-05-20T23:04:00</a:DepartureDate>
                        <a:ArrivalDate>2024-05-21T02:19:00</a:ArrivalDate>
                        <a:LegCount>2</a:LegCount>
                        <a:International>true</a:International>
                        <a:FareTypes>
                            <a:FareType>
                                <a:FareTypeID>1</a:FareTypeID>
                                <a:FareTypeName>ECONOMY</a:FareTypeName>
                                <a:FilterRemove>false</a:FilterRemove>
                                <a:FareInfos>
                                    <a:FareInfo>
                                        <a:FareID>38</a:FareID>
                                        <a:FCCode>T</a:FCCode>
                                        <a:FBCode>TPROI2P5</a:FBCode>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmtNoTaxes>9</a:BaseFareAmtNoTaxes>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmt>9</a:BaseFareAmt>
                                        <a:FareAmtNoTaxes>9</a:FareAmtNoTaxes>
                                        <a:FareAmt>9</a:FareAmt>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmtInclTax>72.62</a:BaseFareAmtInclTax>
                                        <a:FareAmtInclTax>72.62</a:FareAmtInclTax>
                                        <a:PvtFare>false</a:PvtFare>
                                        <a:PTCID>1</a:PTCID>
                                        <a:Cabin>ECONOMY</a:Cabin>
                                        <a:SeatsAvailable>13</a:SeatsAvailable>
                                        <a:InfantSeatsAvailable>0</a:InfantSeatsAvailable>
                                        <a:FareScheduleID>24973</a:FareScheduleID>
                                        <a:PromotionID>0</a:PromotionID>
                                        <a:RoundTrip>1</a:RoundTrip>
                                        <a:DisplayFareAmt>9</a:DisplayFareAmt>
                                        <a:DisplayTaxSum>63.62</a:DisplayTaxSum>
                                        <a:SpecialMarketed>false</a:SpecialMarketed>
                                        <a:WaitList>false</a:WaitList>
                                        <a:SpaceAvailable>false</a:SpaceAvailable>
                                        <a:PositiveSpace>false</a:PositiveSpace>
                                        <a:PromotionCatID>0</a:PromotionCatID>
                                        <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                        <a:PromotionAmount>0</a:PromotionAmount>
                                        <a:ApplicableTaxDetails>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>548</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>47</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>1244</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>1.62</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>1245</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>15</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                        </a:ApplicableTaxDetails>
                                        <a:BundleCode/>
                                        <a:OriginalCurrency>USD</a:OriginalCurrency>
                                        <a:ExchangeRate>1</a:ExchangeRate>
                                        <a:ExchangeDate>2024-04-30T00:00:00+00:00</a:ExchangeDate>
                                        <a:CombinableTrips i:nil="true"/>
                                        <a:ReturnFlightSegmentDetails/>
                                    </a:FareInfo>
                                </a:FareInfos>
                            </a:FareType>
                        </a:FareTypes>
                        <a:FlightLegDetails>
                            <a:FlightLegDetail>
                                <a:PFID>132052</a:PFID>
                                <a:DepartureDate>2024-05-20T23:04:00</a:DepartureDate>
                            </a:FlightLegDetail>
                        </a:FlightLegDetails>
                    </a:FlightSegment>
                    <a:FlightSegment>
                        <a:LFID>131923</a:LFID>
                        <a:DepartureDate>2024-05-02T03:09:00</a:DepartureDate>
                        <a:ArrivalDate>2024-05-02T06:31:00</a:ArrivalDate>
                        <a:LegCount>1</a:LegCount>
                        <a:International>true</a:International>
                        <a:FareTypes>
                            <a:FareType>
                                <a:FareTypeID>1</a:FareTypeID>
                                <a:FareTypeName>ECONOMY</a:FareTypeName>
                                <a:FilterRemove>false</a:FilterRemove>
                                <a:FareInfos>
                                    <a:FareInfo>
                                        <a:FareID>113</a:FareID>
                                        <a:FCCode>T</a:FCCode>
                                        <a:FBCode>TPROI2P5</a:FBCode>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmtNoTaxes>9</a:BaseFareAmtNoTaxes>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmt>9</a:BaseFareAmt>
                                        <a:FareAmtNoTaxes>9</a:FareAmtNoTaxes>
                                        <a:FareAmt>9</a:FareAmt>
                                        <a:BaseFareAmtInclTax>57.21</a:BaseFareAmtInclTax>
                                        <a:FareAmtInclTax>57.21</a:FareAmtInclTax>
                                        <a:PvtFare>false</a:PvtFare>
                                        <a:PTCID>1</a:PTCID>
                                        <a:Cabin>ECONOMY</a:Cabin>
                                        <a:SeatsAvailable>20</a:SeatsAvailable>
                                        <a:InfantSeatsAvailable>0</a:InfantSeatsAvailable>
                                        <a:FareScheduleID>25013</a:FareScheduleID>
                                        <a:PromotionID>0</a:PromotionID>
                                        <a:RoundTrip>1</a:RoundTrip>
                                        <a:DisplayFareAmt>9</a:DisplayFareAmt>
                                        <a:DisplayTaxSum>48.21</a:DisplayTaxSum>
                                        <a:SpecialMarketed>false</a:SpecialMarketed>
                                        <a:WaitList>false</a:WaitList>
                                        <a:SpaceAvailable>false</a:SpaceAvailable>
                                        <a:PositiveSpace>false</a:PositiveSpace>
                                        <a:PromotionCatID>0</a:PromotionCatID>
                                        <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                        <a:PromotionAmount>0</a:PromotionAmount>
                                        <a:ApplicableTaxDetails>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>589</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>15</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>1244</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>1.62</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                            <a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                                <a:TaxID>1246</a:TaxID>
                                                <a:Amt>31.59</a:Amt>
                                                <a:InitiatingTaxID>-1</a:InitiatingTaxID>
                                                <a:CommissionAmount>0</a:CommissionAmount>
                                            </a:ApplicableTaxDetail>
                                        </a:ApplicableTaxDetails>
                                        <a:BundleCode/>
                                        <a:OriginalCurrency>USD</a:OriginalCurrency>
                                        <a:ExchangeRate>1</a:ExchangeRate>
                                        <a:ExchangeDate>2024-04-30T00:00:00+00:00</a:ExchangeDate>
                                        <a:CombinableTrips i:nil="true"/>
                                        <a:ReturnFlightSegmentDetails/>
                                    </a:FareInfo>
                                </a:FareInfos>
                            </a:FareType>
                        </a:FareTypes>
                        <a:FlightLegDetails>
                            <a:FlightLegDetail>
                                <a:PFID>131114</a:PFID>
                                <a:DepartureDate>2024-05-02T03:09:00</a:DepartureDate>
                            </a:FlightLegDetail>
                        </a:FlightLegDetails>
                    </a:FlightSegment>
                    `

I am trying the extract the value of LegCount 1.

It's unclear what form of information you're trying to extract but it's pretty clear that using regular expressions for parsing XML is not the best idea.
Consider switching to XPath Extractor
See XPath Language Specification and XPath Tutorial for more information.
